# Postfix triggering a script

Tags: shell, raspberry-pi, postfix-mta

I've installed Postfix as mail server following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/setting-up-gmail-and-other-email-on-a-raspberry-pi-6f7e3ad3d0e).

I've no problem sending emails. I would like to use the mail server to trigger a shell script each time a mail is received. To do so I've added the following code to the 'aliases' file:

```
myemailaccount: "|/home/pi/Desktop/TestScript/TestShell.sh"
```

The shell is also quite simple, I only try to generate a text file in order to know if the shell has been executed :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Let's check if this works!" >  Output.txt
```

So I've tried to send an email to 'myemailaccount@gmail.com' waiting to see the file 'Output.txt' to be generated but nothing happens. If I run the shell from the terminal, no probs, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that you have setup Postfix to send emails thru Gmail.
To receive emails from outside is another painfully road with a lot of tricky parts.

To receive emails you need a Reverse IP from you ISP and check if port 25 is visible outside. 
Email servers check for this ports to issue SMTP protocol verifications.

Nowadays, you also need a valid certificate to operate TLS and SSL over you server.
You can use *Let's Encrypt* free ones.

Don't forget to setup DKIM, SPF and MX stuff in your DNS.

You also need to setup Dovecot or Courier servers:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/reply_by_email_postfix_setup.html
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-e-mail-server-with-dovecot

If you are confused why do you need both Dovecot and Postfix, [Read This!](https://superuser.com/questions/962074/why-use-both-dovecot-and-postfix)

But you can check this solution, if you don't need too much tech:
[Execute script when new email arrives (Postfix / Dovecot)](https://serverfault.com/a/808340)